# imap_fetchheader returning blank

Tags: php, imap

I am using imap_fetchheader function to get header info of unseen email from Gmail account.

I am using it inside loop of message ids. it gives proper out for some of id and after some it it is returning blank.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $unreadCounterGmail; $i++) {
$headers = imap_fetchheader($mbox, $unread[$i]);
        echo "Loop counter = " . $i . " Message Number = " . $unread[$i] . " Header counter = " . count($headers) . "\n";
        $subject = array();
        $date = array();
        $registrar = array();
        preg_match_all('/^Subject: (.*)/m', $headers, $subject);
        preg_match_all('/^Date: (.*)/m', $headers, $date);
        preg_match_all('/^From: (.*)/m', $headers, $registrar);

        $str = $subject[1][0];
        $rgsmail = $registrar[1][0];
        $receiveDate = $date[1][0];
echo "Reading FROM Gmail Acc :: Subject = " . $str . "  :: From = " . $rgsmail . " :: Date = " . $receiveDate . " \n";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/